Ubuntu journalctl message what is the meaning?
apr 26 19:21:59 daniel-ubuntu-dpc kernel: Linux version 6.5.0-28-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-098) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #29~22.04><br>
-- Boot d9c9ebf4b8d44ccbbf87e4810210737c --

what is the meaning of the above meaning message in journalctl? This message what at 19:21 and the last message was at 19:05. I dont know what happened.
I had an issue. I was gone for 10 minutes and then when I checked back my visualstudio code closed down and my terminal had grey blocks with white borders as symbols for the minimize and close button, when I dragged the terminal it also left behind a black trail. I had been running a python program for 5 hours which might be the reason but I do not know how to fix it. So I want to know if this message is when it happened since nothing happened in the 15 minutes prior even though my pc was one. After my pc bugged I restarted it. I cant remember the exact time.

That's a kernel boot message, issued when your ststem (re)boots. After the system comes up again, the terminal command sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex will show the system logs leading up to the crash /shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the -b -1 option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do sudo journalctl  --list-boots, read man journalctl. For more journalctl help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).
